# Extracting each line from a text after a certain character and extract the result to a table using postgres

Tags: postgresql, fasta

I have a text looking like this:

```
>Sequenz: Test 1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG

>Sequenz 2 1234 Organism: Treponema
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG

>Sequenz 3
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
```

There is not necessarily a blank line between the text chunks and it might be a various number of lines of `'MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGM'`. The only thing, which is known for sure is a `>` before each line.

I want resulting in a table like this:

```
HEADER 
----------
Sequenz: Test 1 
----------
Sequenz 2 1234 Organism: Treponema
----------
Sequenz 3
```

I tried:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(regexp_split_to_table( 'text from above', '\n>'),'([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+\s)');
```

resulting in

```
HEADER
----------
Sequenz
----------
Sequenz
----------
Sequenz
```

and

```
Select regexp_split_to_table('text from bove', '[\\\n>+(.)\\\n]+')
```

resulting in

```
HEADER
----------
----------
Sequenz: Test 1 
----------
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
----------
----------
Sequenz 2 1234 Organism: Treponema 
----------
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
----------
----------
Sequenz 3 
----------
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
```

Comment: does next column always start from ` MTEI`?..

Comment: No, this is just a testfile with not so random text ;).

Comment: try `select unnest(string_to_array( 'text from above','>'));`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. This does not give me only the line after '>' but all the text until the next '>' in one row

Comment: please update question with formatted example of what you want

Comment: I did so actually right before I showed some examples of  what I tried so far. If I did not  I describe  it clear enough I will of course update the question?

Comment: `I want resulting in a table like this:` shows one column data set

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to have :).

Comment: I see you point now :) you wanted to get rid of `MTEITAA...` part? :)

Comment: if @Łukasz answered your question, mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT split_part(regexp_split_to_table(trim(leading '>' from '>Sequenz: Test 1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG

>Sequenz 2 1234 Organism: Treponema
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG

>Sequenz 3
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG'), E'>'),E'\n', 1) AS res
```

Remove `trim()` function if you want to keep first empty row.

Demo: http://rextester.com/LQXY98290

Comment: Works like a charm :). Thank you very much!